# jQuery plugin doesn't work in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a jQuery Plugin to my wordpress site. I already figured out how to make jQuery run, but the plugin still doesn't work. It is this plugin: [contenthover](http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/)

I tried it like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/xenia/assets/js/jquery.contenthover.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//-->
    <![CDATA[//>
    <!--
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('#d1').contenthover({
                overlay_background:'#000',
                overlay_opacity:0.8
            });
        });
     //-->
    <!]]//>
</script>
```

Whatever I try doesn't work. I already included jQuery and the plugin via `functions.php`. When I call the simple `slideUp();` it works, but the `contenthover-plugin` doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

edit:
This is how I also tried it by hook it up in teh functions.php of the theme

```
wp_register_script(THEME_SLUG . '-jqueryMain', THEME_URI . '/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js', array('jquery'));
wp_register_script(THEME_SLUG . '-contenthover', THEME_URI . '/assets/js/jquery.contenthover.min.js', array('jquery'));

wp_enqueue_script(THEME_SLUG . '-jqueryMain');
wp_enqueue_script(THEME_SLUG . '-contenthover');
```

Comment: Have you already tried to enque the script through a hook (check the docs for wp_enqueue_scripts)? Also check the JS console for any messages and post them please.

Comment: yes. i already did this.. both, the jquery-lib and the plugin, are implemented in the head of the page when i look at the sourcecode

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using to enqueue the script? Does the console show any error messages?

Comment: I have edited the question ;) .. no, the console says absolutely nothing

Comment: And the script has been loaded properly (In Firefox you can check the debugger tab of the developer toolbar, the script should not be grayed out)? Also assure if your element exists. Add the following to your JS and check the console: `console.log($('#d1').length);`

Comment: oh.. the the debugger tab of the developer toolbar the plugin.js is gayed out.. how do i fix that? .. I mean, the script is there.. I can see and access it through the sourcecode

Comment: Your `wp_register_script()` doesn't make sense, you register jquery under a different name but provide jquery as a dependency. WordPress will load jQuery twice.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider .. how do you mean that? can you please explain it to me?

Comment: The first argument of `wp_register_script` is the name you give the registered script and the last argument you pass as an array contains the dependencies. So if you add 'jquery' as a dependency altough you have enqueued your own jquery as `THEME_SLUG . '-jqueryMain'` it will add the wordpress version of jquery as a dependency. But see the answer of @Gerald Schneider. You should not include your own jQuery version.

Comment: ok,.. i have tried it out with the original jquery-1.20.2 included in WP and it does not with that.. but it works with the jquery-2.1.4 .. how can i implenemt the higher version?

Comment: I have now enqueued the jquery-2.1.4 by `wp_deregister_script('jquery');
     wp_register_script('jquery','//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js',false,'.2.1.4',false);
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` .. but the plugIn-Jquery is still grayed out :/

Comment: In the Firefox debugger my _jquery.contenthover.min.js_ has a Status-Code _304 Not modified_ and is still grayed out.. but when I look into the sourcecode, it is there .. what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5):

WordPress uses a noconflict wrapper because other libraries also use `$` as the core variable, so `$` is not directly available in WordPress.

If you still want to use `$` in your script, you have to define it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//                              ^-- add the dollar sign here
```

Inside this function `$` will work as expected.

You can read more about it [in the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Note: You should avoid adding jQuery yourself, other plugins or themes might rely on the jQuery version provided by WordPress. Just enqueue the jQuery WordPress provides.